# derivative of a recursive vector-valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a recursive vector-valued function

$$\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}(t-1).$$

To compute the derivative of $\mathbf{y}(t)$ with respect to $\mathbf{W}$, do I need to use the product rule? i.e., is the derivative

$$\frac{d\mathbf{y}(t)}{d\mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{W}\frac{d\mathbf{y}(t-1)}{d\mathbf{W}},$$

or

$$\frac{d\mathbf{y}(t)}{d\mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{W}\frac{d\mathbf{y}(t-1)}{d\mathbf{W}}+\mathbf{y}(t-1)?$$

Comment: How can you ensure that $y$ is defined and hence that diffentiability makes sense on an open subset of the reals?

Comment: Assume that the largest eigenvalue in magnitude of $ \mathbf{W} $ is less than one, so the norm of $\mathbf{y}(t)$ will not get larger.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the $t$-dependence and consider this linear equation and its differential
$$\eqalign{
  y &= W \cdot x \cr
 dy &= dW \cdot x \cr
    &= I\cdot dW \cdot x \cr
    &= (Ix):dW \cr
}$$
where $(Ix)$ is a third-order tensor with components $(Ix)_{ijk}=\delta_{ij}x_k$.  I've written an explicit dot for the dot product, so as to reserve juxtaposition to denote the tensor product. Also note that the colon denotes the double-dot product, $A\!:\!B = \sum_{jk}A_{ijk}B_{jk}$

Anyway, since $dy=(\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}):dW$, the derivative is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial W} &= Ix \cr
}$$